# How to pickle and unpickle objects with self-references and from a class with slots?

Tags: python, pickle, slots

What is a correct way to pickle an object from a class with slots, when this object references itself through one of its attributes?  Here is a simple example, with my current implementation, which I'm not sure is 100 % correct:

```
import weakref
import pickle

class my_class(object):

    __slots__ = ('an_int', 'ref_to_self', '__weakref__')

    def __init__(self):
        self.an_int = 42
        self.ref_to_self = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary({self: 1})

    # How to best write __getstate__ and __setstate__?
    def __getstate__(self):

        obj_slot_values = dict((k, getattr(self, k)) for k in self.__slots__)
        # Conversion to a usual dictionary:
        obj_slot_values['ref_to_self'] = dict(obj_slot_values['ref_to_self'])
        # Unpicklable weakref object:
        del obj_slot_values['__weakref__']
        return obj_slot_values

    def __setstate__(self, data_dict):
        # print data_dict
        for (name, value) in data_dict.iteritems():
            setattr(self, name, value)
        # Conversion of the dict back to a WeakKeyDictionary:
        self.ref_to_self = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary(
            self.ref_to_self.iteritems())
```

This can be tested for instance with:

```
def test_pickling(obj):
    "Pickles obj and unpickles it.  Returns the unpickled object"

    obj_pickled = pickle.dumps(obj)
    obj_unpickled = pickle.loads(obj_pickled)

    # Self-references should be kept:
    print "OK?", obj_unpickled == obj_unpickled.ref_to_self.keys()[0]
    print "OK?", isinstance(obj_unpickled.ref_to_self,
                            weakref.WeakKeyDictionary)

    return obj_unpickled

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = my_class()
    obj_unpickled = test_pickling(obj)
    obj_unpickled2 = test_pickling(obj_unpickled)
```

Is this a correct/robust implementation?  how should `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` be written if `my_class` inherited from a class with `__slots__`?  is there a memory leak inside `__setstate__` because of the "circular" dict?

There is a remark in [PEP 307](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0307/) that makes me wonder whether pickling `my_class` objects is at all possible in a robust way:

> The `__getstate__` method should return a picklable value representing the object's state without referencing the object itself.

Does this clash with the fact that a reference to the object itself is pickled?

That's a lot of questions: any remark, comment, or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you want my_class to be subclassable, be sure to replace self.__slots__ to something like: slots = set(); for cls in self.__class__.mro(): slots.update(getattr(cls, '__slots__', ()))

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would say that subclasses update `self.__slots__`, so I guess that there would actually be no problem with subclassing, right?

Comment: Nope. they don't. :-)  Figuring that out took some time, hence the comment. :-)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mscuthbert/b5d94a78f8559740a270

Comment: Right. This makes sense, too (`self.__slots__` can be directly seen in the class of `self`, without anything hidden). Thanks for mentioning the better slot handling when subclassing.

Comment: Updated the gist to mention that the object can also be inherited by a class that defines a `__dict__` as well, so that should be checked for in the most robust cases as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like what the original post suggests works well enough.

As for what PEP 307 reads:

> The __getstate__ method should return a picklable value representing the object's state without referencing the object itself.

I understand that it only means that the `__getstate__` method simply must return a representation that does not point to the (unpickleable) original object.  Thus, returning an object that references itself is fine, as long as no reference to the original (unpickleable) object is made.